# Appending Additional HREF Link to jQuery fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm attempting to append an additional link to each "event" in my jQuery fullcalendar implementation.  However, the code below results in essentially nothing:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    $(element).find("a.fc-event").after($('<a href="/TEST">link</a>').html("link"));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, each "event" is an <a> html element, with styling.  I'd like an additional <a> element for each event.  So, essentially each event will have two link backs to whatever URL I pass back.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to append this to the `.fc-event-title` instead.

Something like this:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    var eventText = element.find('span.fc-event-title').text() + "<a href='/TEST'>link</a>";
    element.find('span.fc-event-title').html(eventText);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think this would most likely work, but I ended up following the qtip examples they had on their site, and using the "content:" section to embed the HREF.  Thanks!